# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I been working on a website and when i finished everything was working properly then when i published it on **somee.com** i had an error when i tried to log in

**PS.. log in credentials are not from a database, so i don't get why I'm receiving a database related error, and when i go back to visula studio and run the site it works without any errors**

```
        if (TextBoxUserName.Text == "administrator" && TextBoxPassword.Text == "aphamia")
        {
            Session["user_ID"] = TextBoxUserName.Text;
            Response.Redirect("EmpLogin.aspx");
        }
        else
            LabelLogin.Text = "Icorrect Username or Password";

        if (Session["user_ID"] != null)
            PanelLogIn.Visible = false;
```

[image: this is how the error looks like]

Comment: You need to change your connection string to point correctly to the server. Also  this kind of codes are open for SQL Injection and you should always use [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: @S.Akbari I checked connection string, but if the connection string was wrong why is it working fine in visual studio?

Comment: It is not wrong. Your local database address is just different from the server one.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your connection string is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please Change the information of connection-string accordingly to hosted environment i.e database credentials,database schema,data-source etc. Make sure these information are correct